# Vue 2 with Vue CLI - How to make src/static static so I can use images that are in there?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

I'm trying to package my Vue CLI app to package `src/static/xyz.png` such that I can reference it as `/static/xyz.png`.

The Vue docs don't really show how to do this. I need a `vue.config.js` but between here:

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html

and here:

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#html

I can't figure out what I need to do. Any ideas? I've tried lots of webpack stuff but don't know webpack well enough, evidently...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vue CLI projects, files under [`public/` are automatically bundled as static assets](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder), so you don't need a custom config for this. Your image should be stored in:

```
<projectRoot>/public/static/xyz.png
```

Then you'd reference them in your markup like this:

```
<img src="/static/xyz.png">
```

Note that these static assets are not run through Webpack, so they won't be optimized (i.e., the image file size might be unnecessarily large).